# Flickr-like Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, flickr

I have been doing a small research on UI designs for Android for the last few weeks. My main concern right now is the action bar along with tabs. I believe the default android implementation takes to much room on the screen.

Recently I took a look at the Flickr app and I really like how they do this but I am not sure how to implement tabs this smoothly inside the action bar itself.

All help / ideas are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Screenshot of the action bar can be found here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/242865/Screenshot_2014-11-11-11-04-05.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [**this library**](https://github.com/Mirkoddd/TabBarView) on github.
It's an Android Library to help you create actionbar tabs like [**Capitaine train**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.capitainetrain.android&hl=en) app by Cyril Mottier.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a customview in your actionbar and use something like ViewPagerIndicator
http://viewpagerindicator.com/
To setup a custom view in your actionbar just use setCustomView but remember to enable the display of custom view first.
Take a look at this
http://www.jfarrell.net/2013/10/customizing-action-bar-in-android.html